# Calculate average in PIG | and other things

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am new to PIG and therefore an absolute beginner.

I have a .txt file, whose entries look like this:

```html
Name         Matriculation Number Grade Name of Subject           ECTS
John William 078932832            2.7   Research                  5
John William 078932832            2.3   International Management  10
John William 078932832            1.7   Math                      5
```

As you can see, inside the text file there are many entries regarding the same person but different subjects with (of course) different grades. 
I would like to compute the average grade of every single student. For the sample data, I have to do the following to get the average grade:
(2.7 * 5 + 2.3 * 10 + 1.7 * 5)/ 20 (absolute number of ects points). The result for this example would be 2.25. This procedure should be made for every student inside the list. At the end I want to have a spearate .txt file containing the following:

```html
Name         Matriculation Number Average Grade Number of Subjects Number of ECTS
John William 078932832            2.25          3                  20
```

How can I do this with PIG? Since I am a beginner please provide all steps being necessary to get the result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try the following pig script.

```
a = load '/pathtodata' as (name, matrix, grade, subject, ECTS); 
b = group a by (name, matrix);
c = foreach b {avg = AVG(a.grade);count = COUNT(a.subject); sum= SUM(a.ECTS); generate group,avg,count,sum;};
d = foreach c generate flatten($0), flatten($1), flatten($2), flatten($3);
dump d;
```

Make sure your data is tab seperated for running this script, or else use PigStorage('delimotor') in your load command for any others.

Comment: Hello alekya reddy, thank you very much for your help. The script is running fine, but I don´t get the expected results ;(

Comment: did you use tab seperated data ?

Answer (score 0):

The script runs fine, but the average grade isn´t calculated correctly! 
The existing logic is to sum up all grades and divide it thorugh the count. 
But every grade has to be multiplicated with its ects points, and then added to another grade (which has also to be multiplicated with its ects points and so on). After doing this the "grade sum" must be divided through the count of ects points for each student.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
a = load '/piggrade.txt'  as (name:chararray, matrix:chararray, grade:double, subject:chararray, ECTS:long); 
n = foreach a GENERATE  name,matrix,(grade * ECTS) as (totgrades:double),subject,ECTS;


e = group n by (name, matrix);

f = foreach e 

   {
   GENERATE   flatten(group) as (name,matrix),SUM(n.totgrades) as tg,SUM(n.ECTS) as sm,COUNT(n.subject) as sub;
} 
g = foreach f GENERATE name,matrix,(tg/sm) as (Avg:double),sub,sm;
dump g;
```

the input file must be tab delimited

Comment: Hi Sravan K Reddy,

this works like a charm! I don´t know if this is the most short script but it does the job ;)
Is there any possibility to cut everything after the first position after decimal point? For example: The result of avgGrade is 2.672930 => 2.6 should be the output.

Comment: just now i gave answer to the  decimal truncation,please refer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922857/apache-pig-how-to-cut-digits-after-decimal-point/29925186#29925186  if answers usefull.please accept it